# How to edit live TypeScript code in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

In my company we recently adopted sourcemaps generation in our ts -> js -> minification flow.

Without those maps of course code is almost unreadable/untestable, but as far as I can see those maps don't give me the opportunity to live-edit the code and test it directly in chrome: i edit/save it, but the js interpreter run as if I don't.
This force me to have a local copy of the project and run it, instead of try a fix directly in remote.

Is possible in chrome to edit sourcemapped typescript and run it?

Comment: If you do not have a source map then the only solution would be to use the Pretty print option denoted by `{}` in the left bottom corner of file viewer in Sources. And then try to map the code manually.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible because Chrome doesn't have access to / knowledge of the specific TypeScript compiler / config used by your project.

Chrome Devtools does have [Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/) which allows you to map files to a local folder. This would mean that if you have a process watching the TypeScript files for changes, you can live-edit in Chrome which in turn triggers the local TypeScript compiler.